# What is the cheapest or more accessible way to measure day-to-day hormonal activity variation on a patient?

Tags: endocrinology, data, instruments

Let's say I have 24/7 access to a patient and I would like to record a complete profile of his/her hormonal activity throughout a period of time.

I'm interested in the raw data. I want tons of qualitative and quantitative data to study and rearrange later in discrete and continuous arrays to look for insights.

Comment: This is very broad. What hormones in particular? And what is the period of time?

Comment: As broad and complete a profile as possible using instruments that don't cost more than a few thousand dollars and can be acquired by someone who doesn't own a medical license. Time period doesn't seem relevant because any process can be repeated continuously.

Comment: Well can be but might not want to be... Hourly blood tests aren't fun...

Comment: Well I'm not asking if it is fun. But ok I think I see your point. Although 'hourly' tests wouldn't define the period of the test but the sampling rate. I would expect the sampling rate to be meaningful, I'm not going for hourly blood tests if the hourly part is gratuitous, but if hourly blood tests can offer useful insight, then I would definitely go for it.

Comment: Fair answer, so any time over which it could have changed significantly

Comment: Commenting, not an answer: For a few thousand dollars, you can't do it.

Comment: What's your evidence to confirm that statement?

Comment: For those that upvoted the "Very broad" comment, you should also VTC. http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/193/the-road-to-public-beta-time-to-clean-up-qa-on-health-stack-exchange#193

Comment: I doubt rephrasing this question will fulfill SE expectations. I'd appreciate some **health expert** explaining me exactly why it is too broad, and I would appreciate it even better if someone had given me an answer in the likes of "In order to obtain a complete and comprehensive profile of hormone activity you'd need to take N blood samples from X location on a Y-timely basis because hormone activity changes correspondingly with the patient's activity during the day, and for such measures you need Z machine/equipment, to do A, B & C tests that will give you the most complete data under$19000"